# How to scrape all pages of a website and get the meta description in php

Tags: php

I want to scrape all pages of a website and get the `meta tag description` like

`<meta name="description" content="I want to get this description of this meta tag" />`

similarly for all other pages I want to get their individual `meta description`

Here is my code

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'my_function_get_description');

function my_function_get_description($url) {
   $the_html = file_get_contents('https://tipodense.dk/');
   print_r($the_html)
}
```

This`print_r($the_html)` gives me the whole website, I don't know how to get the meta description of each page

Kindly guide me thanks

Comment: use DOMDocument & DOMXPath to process the returned HTML

Comment: How can I do that?
how can I have the meta description of all pages?

Comment: When scraping a website respect their [robot.txt](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt) file and [limit the rate](https://www.zyte.com/learn/web-scraping-best-practices/) of your requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to parse an HTML file is to use `DOMDocument` and, in many cases, combine that with `DOMXPath` to run queries on the DOM to find elements of interest.

For instance, in your case to extract the meta description you could do:

```
$url='https://tipodense.dk/';

# create the DOMDocument and load url
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
libxml_clear_errors();

# load XPath
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$expr='//meta[@name="description"]';


$col=$xp->query($expr);
if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        echo $node->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```

Which yields:

```
Har du brug for at vide hvad der sker i Odense? Vores fokuspunkter er især events, mad, musik, kultur og nyheder. Hvis du vil vide mere så læs med på sitet.
```

Using the sitemap ( or part of it ) you could do like this:

```
$url='https://tipodense.dk/';
$sitemap='https://tipodense.dk/sitemap-pages.xml';

$urls=array();


# create the DOMDocument and load url
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;


# read the sitemap & store urls
$dom->load( $sitemap );
libxml_clear_errors();

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('loc');
foreach( $col as $node )$urls[]=$node->nodeValue;



foreach( $urls as $url ){
    
    $dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
    libxml_clear_errors();
    
    # load XPath
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    $expr='//meta[@name="description"]';
    
    
    $col=$xp->query( $expr );
    if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            printf('<div>%s: %s</div>', $url, $node->getAttribute('content') );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get the description of all pages, not single page, how can I do this?

Comment: like if the website contains 10 pages, I need all the 10 descriptions of each page

Comment: If you have a pre-compiled list of page urls you iterate through that list and use the above to read the meta tag. If you do **not** have a pre-compiled list you would need to try to identify other pages, perhaps by reading `robots.txt` file if it exists ( it does but is not very useful ) or by scanning the initial page for hyperlinks that relate to the same domain and then scanning each page using the list you just compiled. You **might** be able to read the sitemap file and use that as the basis of the scan

Comment: how can I have the other pages description, i don't have pre-compiled list of page urls

Comment: You can use the website sitemap as a reference to get all the available url : https://tipodense.dk/sitemap.xml

Comment: I have 11 `urls` but I got 7 only, what could be the reason? I'm using the above code

Answer (score 1):

You have to look about preg_match and regex expression.
Here it's quite simple :

```
function my_function_get_description($url) {
    $the_html = file_get_contents('https://tipodense.dk/');
    preg_match('meta name="description" content="([\w\s]+)"', $the_html, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/JMcaUh/1

The description is catched by capturing group () and saved in `$matches[0][1]`

EDIT : DOMDocument is a great solution too, but assuming you only want description, using regex looks easier to me !

Comment: Just be aware of the [possible pitfalls of using a RegEx to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)